# Getting gradient descent to work in octave. (Andrew ng's machine learn course, excersise 1)

Tags: machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement/solve the first programming excersise from Andrew ng`s machine learn cours on coursera.
I have trouble implementing linear gradient descent (for one variable) in octave. I don't get the same paramters values back like in the solution but my parameters goes in the same direction (at least I think so). So I may have somewhere in my code a bug. Maybe someone who has more experience than me can enlighten me.

```matlab
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
%   theta = GRADIENTDESCENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
%   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

theta1 = theta(1);
theta2 = theta(2);

temp0 = 0;
temp1 = 0;

h = X * theta;
for iter = 1:(num_iters)

    % ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
    % Instructions: Perform a single gradient step on the parameter vector
    %               theta. 
    %
    % Hint: While debugging, it can be useful to print out the values
    %       of the cost function (computeCost) and gradient here.
    %
    temp0 = 0;
    temp1 = 0;
    for i=1:m
        error = (h(i) - y(i));
        temp0 = temp0 + error * X(i, 1));;
        temp1 = temp1 + error * X(i, 2));
    end
    theta1 = theta1 - ((alpha/m) * temp0);
    theta2 = theta2 - ((alpha/m) * temp1);
    theta = [theta1;theta2];

    % ============================================================

    % Save the cost J in every iteration    
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end
end
```

My exspected results for excersise 1 with theta initialized with [0;0] should be for theta1: *-3.6303* and for theta2: *1.1664*

But I become as output theta1 is *0.095420* and thetha2 is *0.51890*

[image: here's a photo where you can see my function]

This is the formula I use for linear gradient descent.

[image: this is my formula for linear gradien descent]

[image: where in the formula this is h(x)]

**EDIT1:** Edited code. Now I got for theta1:

> 87.587

And for theta2

> 979.93

Comment: In the inner for loop, you are replacing `temp0` and `temp1` `m` times, and then just using the last value

Comment: thank`s i think this might be the bug. I totally didn't see that i am so stupid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now know what my problem was. I am going to describe it quick for anbody who might be intrested in it. So i accidently calulated the avriable **`h`** outside of my loop. So every time in the loop it calulated with the same value.

Here is the fixed code:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
%   theta = GRADIENTDESCENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
%   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

theta1 = theta(1);
theta2 = theta(2);

temp0 = 0;
temp1 = 0;
error = 0;

for iter = 1:(num_iters)
    % ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
    % Instructions: Perform a single gradient step on the parameter vector
    %               theta. 
    %
    % Hint: While debugging, it can be useful to print out the values
    %       of the cost function (computeCost) and gradient here.
    %

    h = X * theta; %heres the variable i moved into the loop

    temp0 = 0;
    temp1 = 0;
    for i=1:m
        error = (h(i) - y(i));
        temp0 = temp0 + (error * X(i, 1));
        temp1 = temp1 + (error * X(i, 2));
        %disp(error);
    end
    theta1 = theta1 - ((alpha/m) * temp0);
    theta2 = theta2 - ((alpha/m) * temp1);
    theta = [theta1;theta2];

    % ============================================================

    % Save the cost J in every iteration    
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end
end
```

Comment: is sum() command is redundant in the above example as the value of theta shows summation over the predicted error ??

Comment: @AbhishekChoudhery I do not understand what you mean.